# how to make custom single .php file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i make a new page single-1.php but i don't call new page . only call single.php
how to use single-1.php. any help me

Answer (score 2):

if you name single-1.php the file, wordpress is try to load it, if the custom post type is '1'. Not a good solution.

If you want to use a template that is different from the standard post for the custom post type, name it 'single-'.php. Wordpress will load it automatically for you!

For further information see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Hope this it help!

Answer (score 0):

don't quite understand what you mean, but maybe this works for you:

single.php:

```
<?php include "single-1.php"; ?>
```